# Convex or Concave Function

Tags: functional-analysis

the problem is: Is the function $\phi(f)=\frac{\sqrt{f}}{2}\cdot\log f$ for $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}_{>0})$ convex or concave.
My idee or  presumption is, that the function $\phi$ is concave, because we have the inequalitiy\[\sqrt{\alpha\cdot f+(1-\alpha)\cdot g}\geq \alpha\cdot \sqrt{f}+(1-\alpha)\cdot\sqrt{g}\quad\text{for}~\alpha\in(0,1).\]

Comment: How do you define convexity of $\phi$?

Comment: We call a map convex, if \\[\phi(\alpha\cdot f+(1-\alpha)\cdot g)\leq \alpha\cdot \phi(f)+(1-\alpha)\cdot \phi(f)\\] for $\alpha\in (0,1)$

Comment: But $\phi( something )$ is a function. Is $\ge$ to be understood pointwise?

Comment: Sorry, the correct definition is $\phi(f(x)).$ f is also a map.

Answer (score 0):

Waht i have so far for $\phi:\mathbb{R}_{>0}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f\mapsto \phi(f)$
$\begin{align*}
-\phi(\alpha\cdot f+(1-\alpha)\cdot g)&=-\sqrt{\alpha\cdot f+(1-\alpha)\cdot g}\log(\alpha\cdot f+(1-\alpha)\cdot g)\\
&\leq -(\alpha\sqrt f+(1-\alpha) \sqrt{g})\log(f^{\alpha}g^{(1-\alpha)})\\
&=-\left[(\alpha\sqrt f+(1-\alpha) \sqrt{g})(\alpha\log(f)+(1-\alpha)\log(g))\right]\\
&=-[\alpha^2\sqrt{f}\log(f)+\alpha(1-\alpha)\sqrt{f}\log(g)+\alpha(1-\alpha)\sqrt{g}\log(f)\\
&+(1-\alpha)^2\sqrt{g}\log(g)]\\
&=...
\end{align*}$